# Numpy Histogram, which point is the density given on?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, histogram, probability-density

When using numpy.histogram, with density=True, the function returns an array with the pdf values at each point. However my question is, does it return pdf values at the leading edge of the bin or in the middle of the bin?

For example, if I have bins 0-1, 1-2, 2-3 etc... will it give me the pdfs at the points 0, 1, 2 etc... or at 0.5, 1.5, 2.5 etc...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each normalized histogram value will give you the estimated probability density for your sample *over the range spanned by its corresponding bin edges*. If you had bin edges *a* and *b* then the corresponding normalized histogram value would be the probability density over the interval [*a,b*).

Intuitively, to estimate density from some finite number of samples you count the number of samples that fall into each histogram bin, then divide by the area of the bin. For infinitely many samples and infinitely small bins this would eventually converge on the PDF of the underlying continuous distribution.

Comment: Right I see. But as far as which would "make more sense," it seems to me that if I'm trying to approximate a pdf using these bin densities, I would assume that as a point, this density is defined in the middle of the bin right?
Also thanks for the answer.

Comment: Your density estimate is constant for *all* points that fall within the same bin - it's not just a point estimate. In general you might expect it to be closer to the true probability density for points that fall close to the center of the bin (although I think it's also possible to construct counter-examples where this is not true). You might also want to look into other methods of [density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_estimation), such as [KDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation).